# Looking for a constant $c$ such that for any $k$ and any $n≥ck^22^k,$ ${n+k\choose k}(1−2^{-k})^n<1.$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I am looking for a constant $c$ such that for any $k$ and any $n≥ck^22^k,$ ${n+k\choose k}(1−2^{-k})^n<1.$

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I understand that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {n+k \choose k} (1-2^{-k})^n = 0.$ Now I want to have somehow an upper bound for $n$.

Comment: The combinatorics increases slower than how $(1-2^{-k})^n$ decreases.

Comment: $c=2\log 2$ should be fine.

Comment: @Gary Could you give more explanations? By the way, $n, k$ are all positive integers